# ubuntu server can't login

Tags: server, system-installation, login, configuration

I need help!
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on vmware.
After rebooting I put the username and password that I wrote during the configuration but doesn't login.
Why? and how can I solve it?
ubuntu is in english with italian keyboard

Comment: Assuming that the error message is "invalid username or password" and that you are certain that you're typing the correct username and password, well, reinstalling is probably the simplest option.